# Require Recaptcha only once per session

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Using the below code, I want a page, where when it's first loaded, it asks for recaptcha verification, then after that, (while the session is valid) it doesn't require it again.
When I click Open Admin Tools after verifying with recaptcha it shows what it's supposed to; it displays recaptcha completed, options:
but when I click test it will just go back to asking me to complete the recaptcha. How do I make it so it only does that once per (valid) session?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin Settings Page</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            ?>
            <p>Please successfully complete the reCaptcha below to access the page.</p>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Open Admin Tools" />
            </form>
            <?php
        } else {
            $captcha;
            if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
                $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            }
            if (!isset($captcha))
                $captcha = false;
            if (!$captcha){
                echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
                exit;
            }
            $secretKey = "secretkey";
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
            $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
            if (intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
                echo '<h2>reCAPTCHA expired</h2>';
            } else {
                ?>
                <p>Recaptcha Completed, Options:</p>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="test" />
                </form>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a temporary workaround, I'm using dynamically changing content via javascript, but I would still like to know if it's possible to do what I asked above.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing `$_POST` for captcha, but you should have saved the captcha status on a session variable.

Where you test for `if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))`, you could test for `$_SESSION['captcha_valid']`. And where you show a text saying the captcha was completed, use something like `$_SESSION['captcha_valid'] = true`.

This way, as soon as the user solves the captcha, this new status remains valid for as long as the session remais valid.